# How can I check for such macro dependence?

Tags: c

I have defined two macros

```
#define the_begin begin = 0
#define the_size  n - begin
```

I'd like to check if `the_size` macro is not been used without `the_begin` since it depends on `the_begin`.

Is it possible to check such dependence?

Comment: That smells like an incredibly painful way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency is already implicitly introduced by using the `begin` variable. If you give it a more unique name, you can mostly be sure that they won't be misused.

You can't be 100% sure, of course, because macros expand to regular text. Specially crafted text will always be able to imitate the effect of a macro, because that's what macros are.

All that said, what you're doing is a **very, very bad idea**. Macros such as those have a direct, negative impact in the ability of a reader to understand the code. **Specially** because, being macros, they can expand to anything -- and the final code that gets executed **does not reflect** what's written.

That's a good recipe for a long night of debugging.

Comment: +1: The only way to check this surely with macros would be to create a macro within a macro, which is, as far as I know, not possible, since the preprocessor doesn't parse the document a second time. But macros are just macros: text-expansions. If they were a turing-complete language on the other hand…

Comment: Rest asured, this pales in comparison to the crap I wrote when I started. Also when I had not so recently started. Happy coding!